# how to delete duplicates in search discover

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i am getting some duplicate results searching in kibana's discover search bar in some documents fields, i wanto to get an unique document from each time of the duplicates. since i'm starting to use this i don't know how to use the query dls to do this. but i would need something like this:

any search :

```
  Doc 1 {log: '0701143900', name: '5018', date: '2019/07/01 14:37:41:796'}
  Doc 2 {log: '0701143900', name: '5018', date: '2019/07/01 14:37:41:796'}
  Doc 3 {log: '0701143900', name: '5018', date: '2019/07/01 14:37:41:796'}
  Doc 4 {log: '0701125212', name: '5018', date: '2019/07/01 12:44:58:595'}
  Doc 5 {log: '0701125212', name: '5018', date: '2019/07/01 12:44:58:595'}
  Doc 6 {log: '0701125212', name: '5018', date: '2019/07/01 12:44:58:595'}
```

after the dsl query i could see this result (deduplication result by date field)

```
Doc 3 {log: '0701143900', name: '5018', date: '2019/07/01 14:37:41:796'}
Doc 4 {log: '0701125212', name: '5018', date: '2019/07/01 12:44:58:595'}
```

(it can be any doc number but without the dupe ones)

Comment: Is there a reason you'd rather solve this by removing the duplicates at query time instead of at index time?  To restate:  How/why are the duplicates being produced and is it possible to prevent them from being indexed in the first place?

Comment: well i don't have permission to touch log data and i'm still waiting for people to remove duplicates, i'ts been a couple of weeks, i wanted to know if i could do that, without relying on anyone, from kibana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Elasticsearch, there's not exactly the type of `SELECT ... DISTINCT` operation that you're looking for, but we can get close (with a few caveats).

*NOTE: All of the following was tested on ES 6.8.1, but should work as far back as ES 2.x and up through 7.x as well.*

Effectively, you can combine two things:

1. A [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) across whatever your uniqueness criteria is (if the `log` field is enough to assert uniqueness, this will be easy.  If it's some combination of fields, this will get [nominally trickier with scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation) and significantly less performant)
2. A [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to return one hit from each bucket of the terms aggregation

### In Elasticsearch...

Assuming:

- Your logs are in some index (for example, named `logs` - locally I indexed your records into an index named `logs-2019.07.01` and aliased it as `logs`)
- The `log` field is `keyword` analyzed (allows it to be aggregated over)

```js
POST /logs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_logs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "log",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return a max of 10 unique records

```js
{
  "took" : 2,
  ...
  "aggregations" : {
    "unique_logs" : {
      ...
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "0701125212",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "docs" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : 3,
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "logs-2019.07.01",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "x-FB2GsBn6OwEwpDhYjX",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "log" : "0701125212",
                    "name" : "5018",
                    "date" : "2019/07/01 12:44:58:595"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "0701143900",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "docs" : {
            ...
          }
        }
  ...
}
```

### In Kibana...

With the same assumptions about index/data above:

1. Use the left-nav bar to go to the `Visualize` builder
2. Create a new Data Table visualization, then select the index pattern containing your logs
3. Select `Top Hits` as your metric (display and sort whatever fields you'd like), and a `Terms` aggregation for bucketing your rows by the `doc` field
   [image: Kibana - Metrics and Buckets config]
4. Running the visualization should create a 2-columned table with the unique criteria in one column and the selected Top Hits `Field` in the other.

That's it!  You should now have a table with one row per "unique" record, as per whatever uniqueness criteria you've defined.

### Options

#### Multi-field uniqueness

If you want to use multiple fields in your uniqueness criteria, without making changes to your mapping/indexing the only option you'll have is to use a `script` in your terms aggregation instead of `"field": "doc"`.  In an Elasticsearch query, this is simple:

```js
POST /logs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_logs": {
      "terms": {
        // Remove the "field" from the agg...
        // "field": "log",
        // ...and add a "script" instead.
        "script": {
          "source": "String.format('%s.%s', new def[]{doc['log'].value, doc['name'].value})",
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        "size": 10
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

In Kibana, you do the same thing, it just takes a few clicks to get there:

1. Add a new [scripted field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.8/scripted-fields.html) that concatenates your desired "uniqueness" fields (use the script from the ES example directly above as a template).
2. In the `Buckets` configuration of your visualization, select your newly minted script field from the `Field` dropdown.

#### Display multiple fields per row in Kibana

While the top hits aggregation supports returning entire hits, unfortunately the Kibana Data Table visualization only supports displaying a single field per row.  If you want to display more data per row, you'll have to create a [scripted field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.8/scripted-fields.html) that contains the data you'd like to display.

Similar to the multi-field unique key example, you can write a script that formats some string w/ some combination of your fields:

```groovy
String.format('[%s] %s - %s', new def[]{doc['log'].value, doc['date'].value, doc['name'].value})
```

### Caveats

1. The more your solution leans on scripts, the more likely it is to become non-performant.  Try to limit scripts wherever possible (i.e. - just use a single field for uniqueness if you can)
2. For the visualization, you might want to create Saved Search *instead* of just creating it directly on the index pattern to limit the number of documents you're searching over and visualizing, since that aggregation might get expensive since it's running scripts.